# how to pass values dynamically to gridview rows using label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've `gridview` which contain `itemtemplate` and inside `itemtemplate` contains `label`. I want to place `text` in `label` which values comes from `codebehind`.
I want this type of `output` in `gridview`.
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsC6f.png)

`Proj_Title` and `Total_Issue` working fine but how to set `label` text against every row .
Here is my aspx code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="g9" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="g9_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project_Title">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("proj_title") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Issue">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RESULT">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="issue" runat="server"  ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="Large" Width="200px"  ></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="issue2" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="Large" Width="200px"  ></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("USE SKDM SELECT  proj_title , COUNT (*) as Count FROM Issue WHERE proj_title is NOT null GROUP BY proj_title", cnn);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
cnn.Open();
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
g9.DataSource = ds;
g9.DataBind();
}
 protected void g9_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
 SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("USE SKDM SELECT  proj_title , COUNT (*) as Count FROM Issue WHERE proj_title is NOT null GROUP BY proj_title", cnn);
 cnn.Open();
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
 int[] arr = new int[2];
 while (dr.Read())
 {
 arr[0] = dr.GetInt32(1);
 }
 if (arr[0] == 2)
 {
 Label l3 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("issue2");
 string s = "BAD";
 l3.Text = s;
 } 
 dr.Close();
 cnn.Close();
 if (arr[0] == 2)
 {
  Label l2 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("issue");
  string s = "GOOD";
  l2.Text = s;
  }
  if (arr[1] == 5)
  {
  Label ab = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("issue2");
        ab.Text = "Poor";
 }
 } 
 }
```

I want when `count` value is `2` then result will be `Good` shown in `Result` column against row and when `count` value is `5` then result will be `Poor` and set label `Result` column .Thanks

Comment: Why not you bind datatable to gridview on pageload ?

Comment: because i want to retrieve values in `gridview` on page load.You suggest me please

Comment: But you will bind gridview on page load then what is you want. I think you confused about binding data in gridview.

Comment: i think that data bind in gridview on row bind that's why i use row bind i also try that on page  load  but  problem in third column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply You Can call a function on your grid from code behind to Design page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="g9" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="g9_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project_Title">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("proj_title") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Issue">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Count") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RESULT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <%#ConvertResult(Convert.ToString(Eval("Count")))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

.CS Page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("proj_title", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Count",typeof(int))});
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "SQl", 2);
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "C#", 5);
        g9.DataSource = dt;
        g9.DataBind();
    }

    protected void g9_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           // i dont use this...
        }
    }

    // Create this function and call this to in your gridview
    // see above in design page
    public string ConvertResult(string strCount)
    {
        string strResult = "";
        int iValue = Convert.ToInt32(strCount);
        if (iValue < 2)
            strResult = "Bad";
        if (iValue == 2)
            strResult = "Poor";
        if (iValue == 5)
            strResult = "great";
        return strResult;
    }
```

**Output Result**
 [image]